# Access URL query Params in an Express POST route

Tags: node.js, express

I have a NodeJS/Express application.

From an url endpoint titled: `localhost:3000/form?someProp=someValue&somethingElse=someOtherValue`

This page submits a form to another Express endpoint.

I submit to an Express POST endpoint. I know in a GET endpoint I could access the query params via `req.query`, but I cannot seem to do that in a POST request.

Is there a way to access the query params from the request in a POST route?
(other than splicing the header.referrer... which I may just have to do)

Here are some code snippets:

If I submit to the first route it works, if I submit to the second... it does not.

```
router.get('/test',
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query); // {someProp: someValue, somethingElse: someOtherValue }
  }
);

router.post('/test2',
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query); // returns {}
  }
);
```

Comment: FYI its an anti-pattern to use query params in a post endpoint. The body of your post should contain the information needed for completing your operation. If that is for some reason not possible then it should be included in the request headers.

Comment: I wish my work understood that :( @WillEvers

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to send a simple request to test it and got everything working without doing anything special (The only thing extra I have is that I'm using body-parser middleware from npm):

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
```

Then I tried this simple route and got the result query params as you can see in the picture attached.

```
http://localhost:8080/test?test=1&what=2
```

[image]

Any chance you're sending the other form request from the client in a different way? try looking at the network in chrome and see if you sending what you expecting. Obviously, there is something missing here as it worked for me without doing anything special.

Comment: Can I see your app definition stuff? Like where you are declaring express and adding the router? We have body-parser too.

Comment: @Chris
I Just used a fresh express init app and also I removed the body-parser for the sake of testing. so have nothing special honestly,

I have an express router which I'm including 
app.use('/', appRouter);
app.listen(port, () => {.....

That's all